# Yii framework 2.0 printing functionality

Tags: php, printing, yii2

I work with Yii framework 2.0. I have retrieved data from the database and I would like to send it to the printer and print it out on paper. As a junior PHP developer I have never print something with PHP (not print/echo, but print on paper). Does Yii framework 2.0 provide any API for printing functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can't print with PHP, because PHP runs on a server, not on the client.

The easiest way to print, is create a normal webpage - view in yii - and define a css with media="print".

If the user want to print out the page (with file -> print menu, or with the JS window.print()), the browser will use the print css instead of your normal css.

In the print css you can define what will be visible on the page, and you can hide (display: none) some part of it.

You can use the following, for adding media attribute to your css file:

[Yii framework 2.0 add media print to css link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452227/yii-framework-2-0-add-media-print-to-css-link)