# Yii framework 2.0 add media print to css link

Tags: css, attributes, media, yii2

Working with Yii framework 2.0 I include a css file with the code below inside ***assets/AppAsset.php***.

```
public $css = [
    'css/style.css',
];
```

When I inspect element on the web browser I see the following code in the header tag:

```
<link href="/locahost/mywebsite/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would like to add the ***print.css*** to the web page with ***media='print'***. How could I add the attribute ***media='print'*** into the css link within Yii framework 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [cssOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$cssOptions-detail) attribute for the Assetsbundle, where you can define the media, but it will add all of your css file registered in that asset.

If you want to use it separately, you need to create a new asset for that.

Within the URL below you can find, how to make a custom asset and how to register it to your app (layout):

http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2013/12/28/adding-fontawesome-to-your-yii2-project-via-composer/

Answer (score 1):

You could add your css to the assets bundle in the following way

```
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
    ['css/print.css', 'media' => 'print'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the $options Array of View::registerCssFile(), like this:

```
$this->registerCssFile('myfile.css', ['media' => 'print']);
```